# Unit tests never ending with jest and strapi

Tags: node.js, jestjs, strapi

I'm using jest to develop my unit tests for strapi.
In the strapi documentation (https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/guides/unit-testing.html#testing-auth-endpoint-controller) they invite the developers to create one `.test.js` file that jest will discover and add all the tests files using requires.

The result is something like this :

```
it('strapi is defined', () => {
  expect(strapi).toBeDefined();
});
require('mytest1.js')
require('mytest2.js')
require('mytest3.js')
```

The problem is that I have, now, a lot of tests, and when I run this huge test file, the execution stops at 81 tests and webstorm display them like if they were still pending.

I tried many jest options like :
--forceExit
--detectOpenHandles
--watchAll=false
--no-watchman

But the problem is still there.

Help !

Comment: add `afterAll( )` at the end of your testing block to see if it is finishing or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hum, it seems that the problem came from one of my test that blocked all the process.

Comment: Could you please develop which one ?

Comment: It was a piece of code that was calling aws sdk, the connection informations were not properly mocked